# db.OpenRecordset returns something that isn't a recordset; but run as queries they do

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to generate a bill by route, so I've broken it down by customers belonging to a specific route, and then for each customer totaling their weekly rates to compile a monthly rate.

The problem is, even opening a recordset with a `SELECT * IN [table]` returns nothing, so there must be some glaring error.  Here's my code, I'd be very appreciative if someone could set me straight.

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs3 As DAO.Recordset
Dim custNo As Integer
Dim month_total_v As Integer
Dim weekTotal As Integer
Dim weekStart As Date
Dim sql As String

'sql = "SELECT cust_no FROM Roster WHERE route = Forms![routeBill]![route]"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT CUST_NO FROM Roster WHERE ROUTE = 'Forms![routeBill]![route]'")

month_total_v = 0

MsgBox ("Boop.")

If Not (rs.EOF) Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
    MsgBox ("Boop.")
        custNo = rs!CUST_NO
        Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT wk_rate, wk_strt_dt FROM Roster WHERE wk_strt_dt >= Forms![routeBill]![Text53] AND wk_strt_dt <= Forms![routeBill]![Text4] AND cust_no = custNo")
        If Not (rs2.EOF And rs2.BOF) Then
            rs2.MoveFirst
            Do Until rs2.EOF = True
                MsgBox "Boop."
                weekStart = WK_STRT_DT
                month_total_v = month_total_v + rs2!WK_RATE
                Set rs3 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM monthTotal where cust_no = custNo and billMonth=month(weekStart) and billYear=year(weekStart)") 'specify date ranges to pick from to shorten query
                If rs3.EOF Then
                    sql = "INSERT INTO monthTotal (cust_no, month_total, billMonth, billYear) VALUES (custNo, month_total_v, month(weekStart), year(weekStart))" 'Append, record does not exist
                    DoCmd.RunSQL sql
                Else
                    sql = "UPDATE monthTotal SET month_total = month_total_v WHERE cust_no = custNo AND billMonth = month(weekStart) AND billYear = year(weekStart)" 'Update, record exists
                    DoCmd.RunSQL sql
                End If
                rs2.MoveNext
            Loop
        Else
            'pass
        End If
    rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query will not return any records when none of the stored *ROUTE* values contain the literal text, *'Forms![routeBill]![route]'* ...

```
SELECT CUST_NO FROM Roster WHERE ROUTE = 'Forms![routeBill]![route]'
```

Elsewhere you have a `WHERE` clause which includes `AND cust_no = custNo`.  But, since *custNo* is a VBA variable, the db engine doesn't know anything about it and will interpret it to be the name of a parameter for which you haven't supplied a value.

You can avoid those types of problems by using a parameter query in a `DAO.QueryDef`.  Then supply the parameter values (from form controls, VBA variables, whatever ...) and use the `QueryDef.OpenRecordset` method to load your recordset.

Here is a simple example ...

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSelect As String

strSelect = "SELECT CUST_NO FROM Roster WHERE ROUTE = [which_route]"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSelect)
qdf.Parameters("which_route").Value = Forms![routeBill]![route]
Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
With rs
    If .BOF And .EOF Then
        MsgBox "no matches found"
    Else
        .MoveLast
        MsgBox .RecordCount & " matches"
    End If
    .Close
End With
```

Note the parameter query technique avoids the need to add quotes around text values (and then also cope with text values which may include quotes within them) and format Date/Time values and enclose them within `#` delimiters.

Comment: Hey, there we go!  17 records returned :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
FROM Roster WHERE wk_strt_dt >= Forms![routeBill]![Text53] AND wk
```

You should outquote Forms![routeBill]![Text53]:

```
FROM Roster WHERE wk_strt_dt >= " & Forms![routeBill]![Text53] & "  AND wk
```

Comment: I think that should be double quotes.  By the name it looks like a date column as well.

Comment: And this only 1 of them, there are more sections which must be changed.
And indeed, it's probably a date field, so Forms!....[Text53] probably has to be converted to a correct date string.
But I think @theCowardlyFrench has enough input to correct his vba.

Comment: I corrected that, and added the formatting you, as well as Gustav suggested.  The odd part is, I have the message boxes in the code for debugging.  I removed the first one, and the second one should appear sixteen times (for one of the routes, at least) because it's returning the customer numbers that match a route.  That doesn't work either, and the message box never appears because the If statement never seems to be valid -- as if the record set were empty.

Comment: `Play Twilight (the show) theme song` If it is acting as if the recordset were empty it probably is.  Test it again with your `SELECT * IN [table]` in your first query again and see what happens.

Comment: I did, same result.  I'm wondering if I'm not actually pulling the recordset, ie. setting it incorrectly.  I don't see anything that alludes to that, but that's exactly what it's acting like.  As if it's failing silently.

Comment: `MsgBox rs.RecordCount` after `Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT CUST_NO FROM Roster WHERE ROUTE = 'Forms![routeBill]![route]'")

`

Comment: Yup, it returned zero.  Thank you for suggesting that and confirming my suspicions.  I deleted the combo box and re-added it, still with no luck.  The query "SELECT cust_no FROM Roster where ROUTE ='Route 4';" returns the desired results, but for some reason the result set remains empty..

Answer (score 0):

You also need to get the dates right:

```
WHERE wk_strt_dt >= #" & Format(Forms![routeBill]![Text53], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# AND wk_strt_dt  ... etc
```